# C++ Djinni return record. Undefined reference to djinni_generated

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, djinni

I try to use Djinni to implement shared Business-Logic for Android and iOS. I keep getting an error for a method that returns a custom record. I use following IDL-Definition and implementation.

audio_book.djinni

```
audio_book = record {
    id: i32;
    title: string;
}

audio_book_service = interface +c {
    static create(): audio_book_service;
    fetch_audio_book(id: i32): audio_book;
}
```

**which generated following files:**

audio_book.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct AudioBook final {
    int32_t id;
    std::string title;

    AudioBook(int32_t id_,
              std::string title_)
    : id(std::move(id_))
    , title(std::move(title_))
    {}
};
```

audio_book_service.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

struct AudioBook;

class AudioBookService {
public:
    virtual ~AudioBookService() {}

    static std::shared_ptr<AudioBookService> create();

    virtual AudioBook fetch_audio_book(int32_t id) = 0;
};
```

**with my implementation:**

audio_book_service_impl.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "audio_book_service.hpp"
#include "audio_book.hpp"

class AudioBookServiceImpl : public AudioBookService {

public:
   AudioBook fetch_audio_book(int32_t id) override ;
};
```

audio_book_service_impl.cpp

```
#include "audio_book_service_impl.h"

std::shared_ptr<AudioBookService> AudioBookService::create() {
    return std::make_shared<AudioBookServiceImpl>();
}

AudioBook AudioBookServiceImpl::fetch_audio_book(int32_t id) {
    AudioBook audioBook(1, "TEST");
    return audioBook;
}
```

When I try to compile it for an Android-Project, it will throw this error:

```
app/src/djinni/generated/jni/NativeAudioBookService.cpp:38: error: undefined reference to 'djinni_generated::NativeAudioBook::fromCpp(_JNIEnv*, lynen::AudioBook const&)'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Why does ist say it is undefined? For native types it compiles without problems. Does anyone have an example to return custom records in djinni or encountered the same problem?

Comment: It seems the linker cannot see generated files. How do you compile it?

Answer (score 1):

The missing function should've been generated into NativeAudioBook.cpp.  Make sure you've included that file in your build rules.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include the generated .hpp-files. My CMakeLists.txt only included generated cpp-files but not any hpp Headers. As Djinni only generates cpp for defined constants. As for interfaces and records djinni, generates hpp-files.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt that fixed the issue:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(support_dir src/djinni/support-lib/jni)

set(include_dirs src/djinni/generated/cpp/ src/djinni/generated/jni/ src/main/cpp/)

file(
    GLOB_RECURSE support_srcs
    ${support_dir}/*.cpp)

file(
    GLOB_RECURSE lib_srcs
    src/djinni/generated/cpp/*.cpp
    src/djinni/generated/cpp/*.hpp // forgot to include. This fixed the issue.
    src/djinni/generated/jni/*.cpp
    src/main/cpp/*.cpp)

set(complete_src ${support_srcs} ${lib_srcs})

add_library(lynen-shared SHARED ${complete_src})

target_include_directories(
    lynen-shared
    PUBLIC
    ${include_dirs}
    ${support_dir})
```

Thanks @atwyman, @mkk for the hint.